# Avoid hyphenation in the whole latex document while reducing Underfull and Overfull \hbox warnings

Tags: overleaf, hyphenation, latex3, thesis

I am writing my thesis using Latex and I don't want it to break words at the end of the lines (in the whole document). For this I added `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` in my preamble.

It worked, but in parallel, I got many 'Underfull and Overfull \hbox warnings'.

To overcome these warnings, I was using the `\sloppy` option and then I replaced it with:

```
\tolerance 1414 \hbadness 1414 \emergencystretch 1.5em \hfuzz 0.3pt \widowpenalty=10000 \vfuzz \hfuzz \raggedbottom
```

But I am still obtaining many warnings and I am lost. Are there any best practices regarding the use of these options? I tried several combinations but with no success. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If you don't want hyphenation set the document with \raggedright.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried with \raggedright but then the paragraphs were aligned to the right. I want them to be well aligned on both the right and left sides.

Comment: you can't have both. Without hyphenation the spacing is bad if you try to justify the paragraph.

Comment: why would you want text justified to both margins but disable hyphenation? Surely best practice would be not to do that

Comment: Yes, I changed my mind. I am keeping the hyphenation and also these parameters: \tolerance 1414 \hbadness 1414 \emergencystretch 1.5em \hfuzz 0.3pt \widowpenalty=10000 \vfuzz \hfuzz \raggedbottom. Now, visually speaking, the typeset seems OK but I would like to have the opinion of Latex Pro people. I appreciate.

Comment: You can't swim and watch your clothes on the shore at the same time. Justifying without hyphens means horrible gaps somewhere with no solution. With `microtype` and/or `\emergencystrech` most times you will avoid a horrible typography, yes,  but when you least expect it, `hypenat` will show his less friendly face.